# How to get the micro seconds cumsum values at time?

Tags: pandas, time, cumsum

How to get the micro seconds cumsum values at time?

It belows Input Data

```
time                     A   B
2018-04-04 00:01:52.474 0.0 0.0 
2018-04-04 00:01:52.676 0.0 0.0
2018-04-04 00:01:52.692 0.0 0.0
2018-04-04 00:01:52.754 1.0 0.0
2018-04-04 00:01:52.817 1.0 0.0
2018-04-04 00:01:52.848 1.0 0.0
2018-04-04 00:01:52.895 1.0 0.0
2018-04-04 00:01:53.051 1.0 0.0
2018-04-04 00:01:53.082 1.0 0.0 
2018-04-04 00:01:53.160 1.0 0.0 
2018-04-04 00:01:53.316 1.0 1.0
2018-04-04 00:01:53.332 1.0 1.0
```

Output Data:

I wanna diff cumsum time get Values in dataframe

```
time                     A   B  cumsum_Time
2018-04-04 00:01:52.474 0.0 0.0   NaN
2018-04-04 00:01:52.676 0.0 0.0   NaN
2018-04-04 00:01:52.692 0.0 0.0   NaN
2018-04-04 00:01:52.754 1.0 0.0   0.0
2018-04-04 00:01:52.817 1.0 0.0   0.04~
2018-04-04 00:01:52.848 1.0 0.0   0.09~
2018-04-04 00:01:52.895 1.0 0.0   0.14~
2018-04-04 00:01:53.051 1.0 0.0   0.32~
2018-04-04 00:01:53.082 1.0 0.0   0.35~
2018-04-04 00:01:53.160 1.0 0.0   0.43~
2018-04-04 00:01:53.316 1.0 1.0   0.52~
2018-04-04 00:01:53.332 1.0 1.0   NaN 
...
```

Output 2 changed values

```
2018/04/04 00:01:52:754 1.0 0.0  NaN  0       this1
2018/04/04 00:01:52:817 1.0 0.0  1    0.06
2018/04/04 00:01:52:848 1.0 0.0  1    0.09
2018/04/04 00:01:52:895 1.0 0.0  1    0.14
2018/04/04 00:01:53:051 1.0 0.0  1    0.303
2018/04/04 00:01:53:082 1.0 0.0  1    0.323
2018/04/04 00:01:53:160 1.0 0.0  1    0.415
2018/04/04 00:01:53:316 1.0 1.0  1    0.562   this2
```

Comment: I dont understand, what is formula? Why last 2 values are NaNs?

Comment: @jezrael That is not using values only A=1 and B=0 Uses.

Comment: @jezrael Is this possible? When A is 1 B is 1 until...

Comment: 2018-04-04 00:01:53.316 - 2018-04-04 00:01:52.817

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], 'time': [ '2018-03-04 00:00:07.130', '2018-03-04 00:00:07.850', '2018-03-04 00:00:08.420', '2018-03-04 00:00:09.210', '2018-03-04 00:00:10.070', '2018-03-04 00:00:10.840', '2018-03-04 00:00:11.230', '2018-03-04 00:00:11.980', '2018-03-04 00:00:12.560', '2018-03-04 00:00:13.120', '2018-03-04 00:00:13.790', '2018-03-04 00:00:14.330', '2018-03-04 00:00:15.280', '2018-03-04 00:00:15.960', '2018-03-04 00:00:16.420', '2018-03-04 00:00:17.090'], 'A': [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]}).set_index('time')`

Comment: Can you add excpected output to this datafarme?

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'time': [ '2018-05-09 09:39:03.926', '2018-03-04 00:00:07.850', '2018-03-04 00:00:08.420', '2018-03-04 00:00:09.210', '2018-03-04 00:00:10.070', '2018-03-04 00:00:10.840', '2018-03-04 00:00:11.230', '2018-03-04 00:00:11.980', '2018-03-04 00:00:12.560', '2018-03-04 00:00:13.120', '2018-03-04 00:00:13.790', '2018-03-04 00:00:14.330', '2018-03-04 00:00:15.280', '2018-03-04 00:00:15.960', '2018-03-04 00:00:16.420', '2018-03-04 00:00:17.090'], 'A': [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,0, 0]}).set_index('time')

Comment: I think how looks new column `cumsum_Time` :)

Comment: 'cumsumTime':[0,0.047,0.083,0.121,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}).set_index('time')

Comment: After 0.121 Just inputs 0, basically 0.121 same values inputs

Comment: Thank you, what is formula for `0.047` and `0.083` and `0.121` ?

Comment: hm.. microsecond at time

Comment: I think what numbers are subtracted from sample data. thank you.

Comment: when sensor A is 1 and Sensor B is 1 that time minus sensor A is 1 and Sensor B is 0 that time.. see that article.. 2018-04-04 00:01:53.316 - 2018-04-04 00:01:52.754.

Comment: OK, do you think `754 - 316` ? It is `438` and I cannot see it in output column. This is why I ask for formula.

Comment: @jezrael Can you see that Output2?

Comment: You add nice sample data, what is problem write formula? How you get your data? What numbers are subtracted for `0.060` ? I want to understand what need, so maybe seems my question stupid, but not, it is not.

Comment: when this2 time - this1 time that second or micro second. Can see article

Comment: I need see numbers, how you get it, like `1-0.94=0.06`, thank you.

Comment: @jezrael 00:01:52:817 - 00:01:52:754 = 0.06

Comment: ok, I try `817 - 754 = 63` . you need remove last 0 and use `810-750=60` ?

Comment: sure, that's not problem